# Not get any Photos using google api

Tags: android, google-photos

I want to fetch all photos of google photos using google api but its return this "{ "items": []}" Every time.I am using this api (https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?spaces=photos&fields=items(mimeType,selfLink,thumbnailLink,title),nextLink&key=AIzaSyCfo2LzK2RU5voHWnlnIXi1k0ZsbAriOu0), I have photos in my google photos account all-ready.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve pictures from Google Photos you need to call GooglePhotos api, not the google drive api. More information how to use this you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started) and [here](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/list)

Comment: Thanks can send me api for retrieve pictures from Google Photos.

Comment: look at this https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started and this https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/list

Comment: Hi Onix thanks, But above link is show implementation in java and php only , if you have any link for android then suggest me.